# How do I show another VP inside the <apex:iframe>?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

How do I use the `<apex:iframe>` to include another Visualsource page inside the existing page using relative URL specifying the width and height? Is it a good alternative to `<apex:include>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a normal `$Page` reference for the `apex:iframe` content e.g.:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:iframe src="{! $Page.MyPageName }" width="100" height="100"/>
</apex:page>
```

Using `apex:include` the content is merged in a single request at the server-side and allows you full control over layout as the result is a single page.

With the `apex:iframe`, the outer page is first rendered and the iframe is filled in a little later which is not ideal for the user. But perhaps most importantly the iframe doesn't automatically re-size to show all the content, and AFAIK it is hard to add JavaScript that works reliably to do such re-sizing. (Not a problem of course your content is of fixed size.)

So my opinion is that `apex:iframe` is not a good alternative to `apex:include`.

Comment: In other words, should I use HTML to specify the width and height? By the way, it also complains that it cannot use public remoted methods inside an `<apex:iframe>`

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs The [apex:iframe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_iframe.htm) tag has width and height attributes that will be passed through to the HTML. Didn't know about the remoted methods problem; I'd stick to apex:include.

Comment: What I meant is if I use `<apex:include>` I don't have the width and height attributes with it.

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs I don't follow what you mean. Check the documentation I linked to.

Comment: What I mean is using `<apex:include>` I cannot specify page size and therefore should probably use raw HTML on the page included.

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs With apex:include you can set the size of the area that the page is displayed in but if the page is too big only part of it will be seen. The apex tags generate HTML and allow CSS to be added so whether or not to use raw HTML depends on the whether the HTML emitted by the tags is helpful or gets in the way. It is generally helpful if you want styling that is consistent with the rest of the UI.

Comment: With the `<apex:include>`, how do I set the size of the area that the page is displayed in?

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs The documentation that I already linked to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_iframe.htm tells you how.

Comment: You have linked to the `<apex:iframe>` page.

Comment: That does define "the size of the area that the page is displayed in". Are you asking how to set the size of the page that is displayed in the frame? You can do that will CSS.

Comment: I do only have the width and height attributes with the `<apex:iframe>` component, but I don't have them with the `<apex:include>`

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs Sorry I missed what you were talking about. With the apex:include the result is one HTML document so you can force width and height in any way that CSS allows; generally though its best to let the content flow (to not hard-code sizes that may not be correct on all browsers or when the content changes) and produce the height that allows all the content to be seen.

Comment: @KeithC Since both pages are under control of the developer, you can indeed have the outer page resize in the inner-page-- simply have the inner page send a message to the outer page requesting a resize, and the outer page can then accommodate it by setting dynamic CSS values on the iframe.

Comment: @sfdcfox ... and because both pages are served from the same domain too?

Comment: That does help, but not strictly necessary, because html5 gives us postMessage, which would allow us to circumvent CORS if we had to. For example, the inner frame could be a Sites page or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `<apex:include>` and wrap your content with `<apex:ouputpanel>` and use style class or style with the `outputPanel`:

```
<apex:include>
<apex:outputpanel style="width:100px; height:100px">
Your content here
</apex:outputpanel>
<apex:include>
```